# C++ if statements

Tags: c++

I cant get my if statements to work. And regardless
of the number the weekend if statement keeps showing up.
I know I asked a similar question earlier, but it just won't work regardless of what I have tried

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
 int day;
    cout << " Enter day of the week " << endl;
    cin >> day;
    switch (day)
{
    case 1 : 
    case 6 : 
    case 7 :
        cout << "weekend";
        break;

    case 2 : 
    case 4 :
        cout << "going to C++ Class";
        break;

    case 3 : 
    case 5 :
        cout << "studying for C++ Class";
        break;

    default :
        cout << "invalid day number";
    }

    if ( day == 1 || 6 || 7)
        cout << "weekend" << endl;
    else
        if (day == 2 || 4)
            cout << "Going to C++ Class";
        else 
            if (day == 2 || 5)
                cout << "studying for C++ Class";
            else 
                if ( day < 1 || day > 7)
                    cout << "bad day number";





    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: change your conditions like this: (day == 1 || day == 6 || day == 7)

Comment: Turn on you compiler warnings and get the compiler to tret warnings as errors and your compiler will catch errors like this for you. A lot of companies require C++ code to compile warning free so it is a good idea to get in the habit.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
if ( day == 1 || 6 || 7)
```

to

```
if ( day == 1 || day == 6 || day == 7)
```

And the same for some similar `if` conditions.

---

Your original test condition `if (day == 1 || 6 || 7)` is equivalent to `if ((day == 1)||6||7)`, always evaluates as true, because all non-zero numbers(in this case, `6` and `7`) are evaluated as true.

Comment: Thank you(: only a freshman in college trying to get my computer science degree. looks like I have a long way lol. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The logical OR operator `||` only operates on *boolean* values, which literal values such as `6` and `7` don't qualify as. You need to separate your conditions into *valid* boolean statements using the relational operators available in C++ `<,>,<=,>=,==,!,etc`. Try using:

```
if (day == 1 || day == 6 || day == 7)
```

`6` and `7` are actually *truthy* values in C++ and will make your condition always true, your current statement is equivalent to:

```
if(day == 1 || true || true)
```

which is *always* true.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ can interpret any numerical value as a logical value. Zero is false, and anything else is true. Therefore syntax like this:

```
if ( day == 1 || 6 || 7)
```

is interpreted as "if (day is one) or (6 is not zero) or (seven is not zero) then..."

A correct way to write this is

```
if ( day == 1 || day == 6 || day == 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

With your `if ( day == 1 || 6 || 7)` it will execute day==1 first which will return either 0 or 1. Then it will go on oring it with non zero(i.e. true) numbers and always gives 1 result i.e. true.

change it to `if ( day == 1 || day == 6 || day == 7)`
                `if (day == 2 || day== 4)` and
                 `if (day == 2 || day == 5)`